# React with Typescript passing objects via props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to pass an object via props and having an issue understanding what Typescript wants.

Do I create an interface for Props than a separate interface for the properties within the object?

**What I have:**

```
import React from 'react';

interface Props { 
  link: object;
}

interface link {
  description: string;
  url: string;
}

const Link = (props: Props) => {
  const { link } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        { link.description }({ link.url })
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Link;
```

**Errors I'm getting:**

```
Property 'description' does not exist on type 'object'.  TS2339
Property 'url' does not exist on type 'object'.  TS2339
```

Comment: The type of link should be link, but I would just inline thag object

Comment: Amazing! Still confused... but it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use it like this, because Typescript can't detect that if the object has property or not:

```
interface Props {
  link: {
    description: string;
    url: string;
  };
}

const Link = (props: Props) => {
  const { link } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {link.description}({link.url})
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Link;
```

Answer (score 4):

`object` is never a good way to type things in TS, as you can't retrieve any information from the object (its properties and much less its properties' types). Also, you're not using this `link` interface that you're creating! You need to use it to type your props:

```
interface Link {
  description: string;
  url: string;
}

interface Props { 
  link: Link;
}
```